# Schema.org - nesting events

Tags: schema.org

I'm currently building an API that will generate a JSON-LD output that will be used by schema.org.

I'm looking for some clarification on how exactly I need to format the JSON, based on the data that I have.

I have a bunch of Events. They have a start and end date/time. They have a name/title and description.

Each event has "sub events". For example:

```
Russian Ballet
  - Russian Ballet Monday
  - Russian Ballet Tuesday

Arts Exhibition
  - Arts Exhibition Thursday
```

The Events and their "sub events" are one-off events.

I've seen the `subEvent`, `eventSchedule` and `offers` (each sub event is a ticket - with no price though)

Which do I use? I kind of need some of each, but unsure how to nest the event data

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An Event that is part of this event. For example, a conference event
>   includes many presentations, each of which is a subEvent of the
>   conference. https://schema.org/subEvent

In general, no way to give you one example to suit all situations.

### complexity

You can nest sub-event inside sub-event inside...inside...

In this example `Child event one` with two sub-events.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context":"http://schema.org",
     "@type":"Event",
     "name":"Parent event",
     "subEvent":[
        {
           "@type":"Event",
           "name":"Child event one",
           "subEvent":[
             {
               "@type":"Event",
               "name":"Grandchild one"
            },
            {
               "@type":"Event",
               "name":"Grandchild two"
            }
            ]
        },
        {
           "@type":"Event",
           "name":"Child event two"
        }
     ]
  }
}
</script>
```

[image]

### Outline example three levels of nesting objects

(eventSchedule inside subevent. subevent inside event)

`eventSchedule` data added to `sub-event one` (Child of Parent event).

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context":"http://schema.org",
     "@type":"Event",
     "name":"Event name - FIFA World Cup 2020",
     "subEvent":[
      {
         "@type":"Event",
         "name":"sub-event one",
         "eventSchedule":{
            "@type":"Schedule",
            "startDate":"2017-01-01",
            "endDate":"2017-12-31",
            "repeatFrequency":"P1W",
            "byDay":"http://schema.org/Wednesday",
            "startTime":"19:00",
            "endTime":"20:00",
            "scheduleTimezone":"Europe/London"
         }
      },
      {
         "@type":"Event",
         "name":"sub-event name"
      }
     ]
    }
}
</script>
```

### Code Example

**(Missing some properties for shorter code)

`FIFA World cup` event with 3 sub-events

- **Quarterfinal** event day
- **Semi-final** event day
- **Final** event day

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Event",
    "name": "FIFA World Cup 2020",
    "startDate": "2020-09",
    "endDate": "2020-11",
    "location": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressLocality": "London",
        "postalCode": "80209",
        "streetAddress": "7 S. Broadway"
      },
      "name": "London Place Name"
    },
    "offers": {
      "@type": "Offer",
      "price": "13.00",
      "priceCurrency": "USD",
      "url": "http://www.ticketfly.com/purchase/309433"
    },
    "subEvent": [
    {
      "@type": "Event",
      "name": "Quarter final - FIFA World Cup 2020",
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "startDate": "2020-09",
      "endDate": "2020-09",
      "location": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "name": "London Place Name",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "7 S. Broadway"
        }
        }
    },
    {
      "@type": "Event",
      "name": "Semi final - FIFA World Cup 2020",
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "startDate": "2020-10",
      "endDate": "2020-10",
      "location": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "name": "London Place Name",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "7 S. Broadway"
        }
        }
    },
    {
      "@type": "Event",
      "name": "Final - FIFA World Cup 2020",
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "startDate": "2020-10",
      "endDate": "2020-10",
      "location": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "name": "London Place Name",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "7 S. Broadway"
        }
        }
    }
    ] 
  }
</script>
```

[image]

[Google Email Markup Tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/u/0/) output screenshot:

[image]

### Nesting objects

The idea of nesting object her not diff from any other nesting data on schema.org (So each tutorial you read about this topic could be helpful for you). 
Start with simple examples like:

- https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList
- https://schema.org/itemListElement

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I was just confused if i should create an eventSchedule or subEvent, but your great example shows the subEvent perfectly!

Comment: this answer should be featured by Stackoverflow as the type of answer all responders should emulate.